# Manage user access to pages in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider, roleprovider

I am using MembershipProvider and currently a have 3 roles:
User, Super User, Admin.

Also I have pages that can be seen only by Admin and Super User.
For these pages a I use configuration in web config:

```
  <location path="Users.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin, Super User"/>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

And this works perfectly fine.

But I have bunch of pages

```
Evaluations
Actions
Reports
Files
```

to which a I want separate access. I want grant access to each page individually.

Is there better way to do it than create roles for each page and than assign to these roles?

P.S.
I am using ASP.NET, not MVC

Comment: Not sure if you're using MVC or not (guesing not) but I extended `AuthorizeAttribute` here to check individual permissions rather than roles, might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11145719/1324019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, modify your folder structure to be something like this:

```
- Super User
  - Admin
    - All
```

And then you can do stuff like this:

```
<location path="Super User">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Super User"/>
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>

<location path="Super User/Admin">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Admin"/>
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>

<location path="Super User/Admin/All">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

And now simply place the pages in the appropriate folders. Per the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the location element applies to all sub-directories:

> Specifies the resource that the contained configuration settings apply to. Using location with a missing path attribute applies the configuration settings to the current directory and all child directories. If location is used with no path attribute and allowOverride is False, configuration settings cannot be altered by Web.config files that are in child directories.

so `Super User` by definition will have access to all other pages below and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a better a simpler way. Put all your restricted pages in a separate folder and create an additional web.config in this folder. This additional web.config should contain the authorization section only.

The runtime will evaluate your web.configs from the request folder up to the application root. Because the authorization section exists in this additional web.config it will overwrite your root authorization section.

This way a single setting (single web.config) can guard arbitrary number of files (all files in the directory).

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign permissions to a folder instead using the `<location>` element.  This way, you can group a bunch of pages into one permission set.  Also, you could validate permissions in code; in global.asax, the application_postauthenticaterequest runs for each request to the server (so for each aspx page), and you can write code here to do the validation, and redirect away if the user doesn't have the permissions.