# Grouping roles in Membership provider in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-roles

I have already asked similar question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070254/manage-user-access-to-pages-in-asp-net)

I have basic user Roles:

```
-Admin
-Super User
-User
```

For this roles I manage site permission. Like adding new users or changing their profiles.

Also i have bunch of pages in my app, like

```
-Evaluation.aspx 
-Action.aspx 
-Properties.aspx
```

and so on.
I want to be able to grant access to each page individually for each user.

I think about roles. 
I add `User` to `Evaluation`role and he can browse `Evaluation.aspx`.

Each page in this approach has it's own role-based access model. So I will have more roles in my membership provider.

```
-Evaluation
-Action
-Properties
```

Then I can easy set page access policy in `web.config`.

```
<location path="Users.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin, Super User"/>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

The problem is that `aspnet_Roles` in `Membership provider` becomes quit messy.
And I have to filter roles whenever I deal with them.

For example I have `List<string>` with user type roles:

```
private readonly List<string>  UserTypeRoles = new List<string> {"Users", "Super User", "Admin"};
```

And when I want to bind `CheckBoxList` control with `PagePermissionRoles` I have to do smth like this:

```
private IEnumerable<string> UserSectionRolesGet(string userName)
{
    return Roles.GetRolesForUser(userName).Except(UserTypeRoles);
}
```

Is there way to create 2 type of roles: `UserTypeRoles` and `PagePermissionRole` to provide separate storage and handling.

I don't really want to override existing build-in asp.net membership provider.

Comment: _"I don't really want to override existing build-in asp.net membership provider."_ Why? You don't need to reinvent the wheel and inherit from the abstract  `MembershipProvider`. Since you've already mentioned `aspnet_Roles` you're using the `SqlMembershipProvider`. You can extend it just with the functionality you need.

Comment: I don't really know how to start.

Is it good idea to create `new table` with `page permission roles` and then `validate` them `like Roles.IsUserInRole`?